Espresso does not match the found intents
I tried to mock the following using Matcher<Intent> on Android Espresso:
Intent { act=android.intent.action.CHOOSER (has extras) } handling packages:[[android, com.android.systemui]], extras:
[Bundle[{android.intent.extra.CHOSEN_COMPONENT_INTENT_SENDER=IntentSender{531e378: 
android.os.BinderProxy@5c9a51}, 
android.intent.extra.INTENT=Intent { act=android.intent.action.SEND typ=text/plain flg=0x1 clip={text/plain {T(148)}} (has extras) }, 
android.intent.extra.TITLE=}]]

as
Matcher<Intent> intentMatcher = allOf(hasExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT,
                hasAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND)),
                hasType(MIME_TYPE_TEXT_PLAIN),
                hasExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, ""));

Matcher<Intent> expected = allOf(hasAction(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER),
                hasExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CHOSEN_COMPONENT_INTENT_SENDER, intentMatcher));

intended(expected);

but it is wrong, and am I missing something?

Try replacing hasExtra("Key", Matcher<?>) with hasExtra(is("Key"), Matcher<?>)
Matcher<Intent> intentMatcher = allOf(hasExtra(is(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT),
                hasAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND)),
                hasType(MIME_TYPE_TEXT_PLAIN),
                hasExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, ""));

Matcher<Intent> expected = allOf(hasAction(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER),
                hasExtra(is(Intent.EXTRA_CHOSEN_COMPONENT_INTENT_SENDER), intentMatcher));

intended(expected);


Explanation:
I vaguely recall having similar problems. I think it has to do with the fact that hasExtra has (too) many overloads.
When you do this:
hasExtra("StringKey", intentMatcher)

You reasonably think that Expresso will invoke intentMatcher.matches() on the value of the extra and determine if it matches.
However, thanks to the fun of generics, and the aforementioned multiple overloads, hasExtra(String, Matcher<Intent>) does not resolve to hasExtra(String, Matcher<Object>) - it resolves to hasExtra(String, T) (I assume because Matcher<Object> is not explicitly the sames as Matcher<Intent> so it favors the generic version).
This means that Espresso is checking if the value of the extra is literally a Matcher<Intent> object. Oops!
By changing it to hasExtra(is("Key"), Matcher<?>), you force Espresso to use the only overload with that signature ensuring that it uses the matcher as intended instead of as a literal object.
